# pom.xml greyed out when importing maven project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

In eclipse Mars, I could always clone a git repository and then import it as a maven project. But this time, the pom.xml is greyed out. On the next screen only the pom of another project is showing and I can't proceed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have not already imported the project into the workspace?Maybe you just don't see it because you are using working sets and the project is not in the group you'd expect it to be?

Comment: Indeed, I was importing the wrong project. You can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you have not already imported the project into the workspace? Maybe you just don't see it. One reason can be that you are using working sets and the project is not in the group you'd expect it to be in?

Answer (score 1):

If the project is already imported into your workspace, and you are trying to import another copy of the same project that resides in a different folder, you can try adding some string for Name Template under Advanced and the importing.